# JavaScript objects missing from Microsoft Web Browser window

Tags: javascript, html, vba

I am attempting to show a live webpage in a PPT using the Microsoft Web Browser.  The site I am attempting to access requires a username and password.  The text box objects to accept my username and password do not show within the Web Browser window (I believe they are JavaScript elements).  [image: Difference in Web Browser and Chrome]

I think there are two possible solutions to this problem but I am not sure how to implement either.

1. Alter the code behind the Web Browser window to force it to show these elements.
2. Alter the code behind the Web Browser window to search for these elements (even if they aren't displaying) and fill them with the correct username and password.

I have included the code that I am currently using to display the URL below.

```
Option Explicit  
Private Sub WebBrowser2_DocumentComplete(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant)  
Const URL_LINK = "example_URL"  
On Error Resume Next  
If URL = "" Then WebBrowser2.Navigate URL_LINK  
End Sub
```

I have been trying to find a solution to this problem for quite a while.  Any help or insight would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Simon, it's my first time posting on here.

Comment: I think I may have found a solution to this, but I really need some advice on implementing it.  It seems that you can edit the registry for the Web Browser Control to allow it to run in an IE9 environment rather than the default IE7 environment.  Unfortunately, this edit is per application, but because I am opening the Web Browser in PPT, there is no application to apply the registry hack to... Any ideas?